# The pop-up "please consider adding a comment" wraps awkwardly on mobile site

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, popups

The positioning of text in this pop-up seems wrong: it's pushed way down.

[image]

This is the message shown after each downvote to a user under 2000 reputation. Screenshot from Opera 26 on Android 4.4.

---

I can also reproduce the above in a desktop browser (Chrome) by switching to mobile theme and reducing the width of the window. When the window is wide enough to avoid linebreaks, the issue disappears:

[image]

The same Opera 26 / Android combo shows other  such messages  correctly:

[image]

Comment: Just a note here: Opera now uses the same Webkit rendering engine as Chrome and Safari

Comment: Since when is +1/-1 disallowed in comments? And there's even an automated check for it?